# Read a list from textfile and group it by an attribute in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, list, maven

I have a dynamic list (pipe delimited) inside a file and read as below example:

```
Obama|United States|50|Male
Kennedy|United States|80|Male
Demers|Canada|50|Female
Trump|Unites States|60|Male
Mcneill|Canada|65|Male
```

I already read the file from the path and put it into a list.
Now, I need to group it by countries but I'm not exactly sure why I'm not able to call the Leader class to group it by countries.

```
Arrays.stream(ResourceUtils.getFile("c:/leader/leaderlist/").listFiles())
    .filter(File::isFile)
    .forEach(file -> {
        try {
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
            String[] value_split = content.split("\\|");            
            List<String> report_list = Arrays.asList(value_split);  
            Map<Object, List<Leader>> map = report_list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.country));
            System.out.println(map);         
        }

class Leader {
    String name;
    String country;
    String age;
    String sex;

    Report(String s_name, String s_country, String s_age, String s_sex) {
        this.name = s_name;
        this.country= s_country;
        this.age= s_age;
        this.sex= s_sex;

    }
    }
```

Expected result:

```
<LeaderList country="United States">
<Leader name="Obama"> <age="50" sex= "Male" /> </Leader>
<Leader name="Kennedy"> <age="80" sex= "Male" /> </Leader>
<Leader name="Trump"> <age="60" sex= "Male" /> </Leader>
</LeaderList> 
<LeaderList country="Canada">
<Leader name="Demers"> <age="50" sex= "Female" /> </Leader>
<Leader name="Mcneill"> <age="65" sex= "Male" /> </Leader>
</LeaderList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting once, but you need to split over newlines *and* pipes.

```java
String fileContent = "Obama|United States|50|Male\r\n" + "Kennedy|United States|80|Male\r\n"
        + "Demers|Canada|50|Female\r\n" + "Trump|Unites States|60|Male\r\n" + "Mcneill|Canada|65|Male";

List<String> vals = Arrays.asList(fileContent.split("\r\n"));
Map<String, List<Leader>> leaders = vals.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.mapping((val) -> val.split("\\|"),
                Collectors.mapping(
                        (leaderArgs) -> new Leader(leaderArgs[0], leaderArgs[1], leaderArgs[2], leaderArgs[3]),
                        Collectors.groupingBy((leader) -> leader.country))));
```

Comment: it gives an error cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Object>> to Map<String,List<Leader>>

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 1.8

Comment: Without more information, I don't really know what to say. The snippet I shared works with  the Leader class you provided, except for the constructor name.

Comment: It only happens when I set <Leader> to call the Leader class.