# ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Object>> to Map<String,List<>>

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mismatch

I have a list to group by using an attribute. I'm not sure why I'm getting an error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,List> to Map<String,List<MyClass.Leader>>

when calling the Leader class. I'm using Java 8.

````java
Map<String, List<Leader>> reports = vals.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.mapping(val -> val.split("\\|"),
            Collectors.mapping(leaderArgs -> new Reports(leaderArgs[0], leaderArgs[1], leaderArgs[2], leaderArgs[3]),
                Collectors.groupingBy(leader -> leader.country))));

```java
public class Leader {
    String name;
    String country;
    String age;
    String sex;

    Leader(String name, String country, String age, String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
````

Comment: This doesn't compile - you are using 4 names for your class -  `Leaders`, `Reports`, `Leader`, `Report`. Change all those to just `Leader ` and it is ok.

Comment: @greg-449 still get the same error.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? The corrected code is fine on the current Eclipse 2021-03

Comment: @greg-449 I'm using Eclipse Photon v4.8.0

Comment: Also im using Spring Boot - Maven

Comment: Well Eclipse Photon is now 11 releases out of date, there may well have been fixes to the type inference code for streams in newer releases since this is a very tricky area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the same thing as your code but splits up the collect in to multiple map steps, this may work better for you:

```java
Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\|");

Map<String, List<Leader>> result =
      vals.stream()
          .map(splitPattern::split)
          .map(leaderArgs -> new Leader(leaderArgs[0], leaderArgs[1], leaderArgs[2], leaderArgs[3]))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(leader -> leader.country));
```

I have also used `Pattern` which will be a bit faster than repeated calls to String.split.

Simple XML output for this might be:

```java
result.entrySet()
    .forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println("<LeaderList country=\"" + entry.getKey() + "\">");

        entry.getValue()
             .forEach(leader -> System.out.println("<Leader name=\"" + leader.name + "\" age=\"" + leader.age + "\" sex=\"" + leader.sex + "\">"));

        System.out.println("</LeaderList>");
    });
```

The collect code is assuming the input `vals` is a stream of String with one entry per line. For example to read a file:

```java
Path path = ... file path

try (Stream<String> vals = Files.lines(path))
  {
    ... the collect code
  }
catch (final IOException ex)
 {
   // TODO error handling
 }
```

Note: It is important to use a try-with-resources block with `Files.lines` so that the stream is closed properly.

Comment: I get the error "The method map(splitPattern::split) is undefined for the type List<String>"

Comment: Sorry, missed a call to `stream()` copying from my test code. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes I already added the stream() but it gives an error "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)"

Comment: It should not be necessary but you could try `.map((String line) -> splitPattern.split(line))` for the split line or try the original `.map(val -> val.split("\\|"))`. Also make sure all the rest of the stream is correct as error messages for streams can be misleading.

Comment: The error is gone. but it doesn't do the grouping. It only prints the country not my expected result here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67094886/read-a-list-from-textfile-and-group-it-by-an-attribute-in-java

Comment: The code above just produces a Map, it does not print anything because that is not what you asked in this question. In my tests the Map is correct. It sounds like you may not be dealing with the Map correctly in your printing code.

Comment: I have added some example XML output code

Comment: Thank you it works! the only problem is it only prints one line. I wanted to list it all group by country.

Comment: In my tests this prints exactly what you asked for. Ask a new question showing all your code as a [mre]

Comment: I have added code to show how to use this code reading a file using `Files.lines`

Comment: I have  String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())); and                 List<String> vals = Arrays.asList(content);
to read the textfile from path.

Comment: That just gives you a single entry in the list. Files.lines is the correct thing to use.

Comment: You're correct. But now it gives me error. The method stream() is undefined for the type Stream<String> when Im trying to stream the vals.

Comment: Once you are using Files.lines you already have a stream so you don't need to call `stream()` again, just remove the .stream()

Comment: Here's my path. Path path = Paths.get("d:/leaderfile/"); inside that path, is the textfile is the leader.text. It seems that it does not read the textfile from the code you gave.

Comment: The path is the **FULL** path of the file "d:/leaderfile/leader.txt"

Comment: But the file inside the folder changes.

Comment: Then use something like `Files.list` to get a list of files in the folder and then call `Files.lines` on each file you find.

Comment: There's only one textfile that changes, not list. But thank you so much for help. Thank you!